# HTTP Status 500 for Java REST Application

Tags: java, rest, netbeans, amazon-web-services

I keep getting this error when trying to access my .wadl file on my EC2 server (deployed using Elastic Beanstalk). Any ideas what it means/ how to fix it?

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet ServletAdaptor threw exception
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:680)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:928)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:539)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:298)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)

 root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/criteria/Expression
java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2406)
java.lang.Class.getConstructors(Class.java:1476)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.modelapi.annotation.IntrospectionModeller.createResource(IntrospectionModeller.java:111)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.getAbstractResource(WebApplicationImpl.java:745)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.createAbstractResourceModelStructures(WebApplicationImpl.java:1522)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1295)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:169)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:775)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:771)
com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:771)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:766)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:488)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:318)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:609)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:556)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:680)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:928)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:539)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:298)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
root cause

 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.criteria.Expression
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1688)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1533)
java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2406)
java.lang.Class.getConstructors(Class.java:1476)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.modelapi.annotation.IntrospectionModeller.createResource(IntrospectionModeller.java:111)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.getAbstractResource(WebApplicationImpl.java:745)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.createAbstractResourceModelStructures(WebApplicationImpl.java:1522)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1295)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:169)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:775)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:771)
com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:771)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:766)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:488)
   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:318)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:609)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:556)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:680)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:928)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:539)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:298)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
```

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.23 logs.

Comment: It looks like the jpa jar is not in your classpath. It may be called "persistence-api.jar". What jars do you include under WEB-INF/lib ?

Comment: Jersey usually throws a 500 status when you have an unchecked Java exception in your code. In this case, the ClassNotFoundException.

Answer (score 0):

Error code 500 is usually thrown when there is some sort of error in the server, 
like an uncaught exception. 
I mentioned this example as this is your case, see this part of the log:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.criteria.Expression org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1688) org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:153
```

You're probably using JPA in your code, but the JPA jars are not in your WEB-INF/lib directory. 
Please check your webapp structure , fix, and redploy.